# find most repeated value without using group by

Tags: sql, database

I want to find the most repeated category in products without using group by

```
SELECT 
   MAX(COUNT(c.CategoryID) OVER (PARTITION BY c.CategoryName)) 
FROM [Categories] c left join Products p on c.CategoryID=p.CategoryID`
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: i use mysql ......

Answer (score 0):

you cannnot use MAX

but you can Order It

```
SELECT TOP 1
   COUNT(c.CategoryID) OVER (PARTITION BY c.CategoryName) countr 
FROM [Categories] c left join Products p on c.CategoryID=p.CategoryID
ORDER BY countr DESC
```

Comment: I only want one record returned

Comment: top 1 returns only 1 row with the highest count , have you tested it